# Formatting columns depending on column headers

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro where it changes the formatting of the cells depending on the column header.

Header_2 needs to be PROPER case, 
Header_3 needs to be UPPER case,
all column headers need to be UPPER case.

I've over simplified the example, but in reality I have 80 columns with an average of 3,000 rows with blanks within the columns - thus the macro needs to run without me selecting or specifying the range.

Below is my code so far - although I keep getting 'mismatch' error (not sure how to fix it)

Thanks in advance for any insight or help you are able to provide!

Here is my data:

[image]

```
 Sub Proper_text()



Dim i As Integer


For i = 1 To 80
    If Cells(1, i).Value = "HEADER_2" Then

        For Each cell In Columns(i)

            If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then

                cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(cell.Value)


            End If

        Next cell

    End If
Next i



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Public Sub Proper_text()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ur As Range, fr As Long, lr As Long, lc As Long, x As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set ur = ws.UsedRange
    fr = ur.Row
    lr = ur.Row + ur.Rows.Count - 1
    lc = ur.Column + ur.Columns.Count - 1

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each x In ur.Range(ur.Cells(fr, ur.Column), ur.Cells(fr, lc))
        x.Offset(, lc).Formula = "=UPPER(" & x.Address(False, False) & ")"
    Next

    For Each x In ur.Range(ur.Cells(fr + 1, ur.Column), ur.Cells(fr + 1, lc))

        If UCase(x.Offset(-1).Value2) = "HEADER_2" Then
            x.Offset(, lc).Formula = "=PROPER(" & x.Address(False, False) & ")"
        Else
            x.Offset(, lc).Formula = "=UPPER(" & x.Address(False, False) & ")"
        End If

    Next

    Set x = ws.Range(ws.Cells(fr + 1, lc + 1), ur.Cells(fr + 1, lc * 2))
    x.AutoFill Destination:=ur.Range(ur.Cells(fr + 1, lc + 1), ur.Cells(lr, lc * 2))

    ur.Range(ur.Cells(fr, lc + 1), ur.Cells(lr, lc * 2)).Copy
    ur.Range(ur.Cells(fr, ur.Column), ur.Cells(lr, lc)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    ur.Range(ur.Cells(fr, lc + 1), ur.Cells(fr, lc * 2)).EntireColumn.Delete

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ws.Cells(1).Select
End Sub
```

---

Result

```
Before:                                     After:

HEAser_1    HEADer_2    heaDER_3            HEASER_1    HEADER_2    HEADER_3
--------    --------    --------            --------    --------    --------
    1       sTphn       pRCELL               1          Stphn       PRCELL
    2       ADIL        mlr                  2          Adil        MLR
    3       Mlling      sNN                  3          Mlling      SNN
    4       Rosemary    Irvine               4          Rosemary    IRVINE
    5                                        5
    6       JIA         pAn                  6          Jia         PAN
    7       MAJID       doost                7          Majid       DOOST
    8       WILLIAM     smith                8          William     SMITH
    9                                        9
   10       VIssUT      domklAng             10         Vissut      DOMKLANG
   11       RoDNy       mCdermid             11         Rodny       MCDERMID
   12       RoBrt       pACker               12         Robrt       PACKER
   13       PAUL        retz                 13         Paul        RETZ
   14       TRoY        mACpherson           14         Troy        MACPHERSON
   15       CATHRYN     stAfford             15         Cathryn     STAFFORD
```